# Google Assistant Action to send a message to Assistant without voice trigger

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I´m trying to make a custom action or app for google assistant that sends information to the user without a voice trigger having to occur. I already have an flask app running at an url that can receive a POST request from Google and answer it. What I want to do is to have a routine running in my python code, for example a function that checks certain value from a local file, and whenever a condition triggers on that value (for example: value > threshold) I want my code to send a message to the assistant to notify the user. What I mean is something like the following flow:

1. The user triggers the action that is fulfilled in my app running at an url.
2. The app checks some value and once a condition is met notifies the user.
3. If the condition is met again, the user has to be notified again.
4. The user should only have to issue the voice trigger once, and be notified while the assistant is running.

If I havent made myself understood just ask and I will try to explain myself better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications) to a user's phone once they've enabled it for your action. However you wouldn't be able to continually use the system to send voice messages without user interaction.